# OpenFace error de openblas en cmake build

Tags: macos, cmake

necesito instalar la herramienta de OpenFace en macOS Monterrey para un proyecto pero al seguir las instrucciones del repositorio: https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki/Mac-installation me da un error de "could not find OpenBLAS" en la instrucción "cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE .." tanto como para instalación con el archivo .sh como para la instalación manual.

Revisé y openblas si esta instalado, lo reinstalé y el error sigue apareciendo el mensaje "could not find OpenBLAS" en el make build. Actualmente uso la versión 12.4 de macOS Monterrey con el procesador m1.

He revisado otras formas de instalar OpenFace pero igual falla el openblas. He modificado el .bash_profile añadiendo las rutas a los archivos .a y carpeta lib/ de openblas y sigue el mismo error. Adjunto imagen de los errores que obtengo.

[image: OpenFace-could not find OpenBLAS]

[image: openblas versión]